# What time would vs. what time will

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> Sally: You will have to meet my parents tomorrow.
>
> Jack: What time **would/will** it be?

I think that I will have to use *will* in this case, as the situation is likely to happen, but using *would* sounds more polite. Which one must I use in this situation?

Comment: I don't think "would" denotes a politeness here. I think it expresses uncertainty.

Comment: I think "that" would sound better: *What time would/will **that** be?* I agree that "would" expresses Jack's uncertainty -- he does not seem to be so sure that he will in fact meet Sally's parents.

Comment: Neither is more polite than the other. _"What time would it be?"_ could, depending on tone of voice and the relationship between Sally and Jack, express a degree of skepticism about the time of the meeting, or whether it will really take place. _"What time will it be?"_, on the other hand, is a straightforward request for the time of the meeting, with nothing else inferred or implied.

Comment: @P.E.Dant this is correct and IMO could be a good Answer if you expanded on it a little!

Comment: @P.E.Dant What do you mean by a degree of skepticism about the time of the meeting? I'm not understanding it.

Comment: @konte The modal conditional verb _would_ in the sentence could be interpreted by the listener as expressing slight doubt, uncertainty, or skepticism about the time of the meeting or the meeting itself. The tone of voice, and the context of the conversation, may also influence how the statement is perceived. See also **[this question.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/108110/37009)**

Answer (score 1):

Although "would" can be used for politeness, that behaviour is usually for requests and commands:

> Do you want tea? / Would you like tea?
>
> Come with me. / Would you please come with me?

Here, alternating with a future tense, it does not indicate politeness, as the above commenters agree. Instead, this is the more general purpose of the conditional: it indicates a hypothetical scenario.

So the future tense would indicate that it will definitely happen:

> What time **will** that be?
>   
> *Here, Jack has already agreed to meet Sally's parents, even though he has not explicitly said so. In fact, he assumes that she knows him well enough to count on his agreement and that she has already scheduled a time in advance!*

But the conditional tense does not yet agree that it will happen:

> What time **would** that be?
>   
> *Here, Jack has not yet agreed to meet Sally's parents tomorrow. Instead, he implies that whether or not he can accept depends on what time she was planning to set the meeting for, because he might have a schedule conflict.*

If you want to make him more or less polite, you can phrase the whole thing differently. Here are a few options (all of them assume that he is agreeing to come).

> **More polite**
>   
> → Okay. Did you have a time in mind?
>   
> → What time would you like me to come? (Note: "would you like" is the conditional of politeness!)
>   
> → What time works for you?
>
> **Less polite**
>   
> → What time?
>   
> → When do you want me there?
>   
> → Lunch? Dinner?